# Minimizing union of overlapping rectangles

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Believe it or not, this has something to do with making triangle-free graphs bipartite...

We have a collection of $k$ axis parallel rectangles with side lengths $(a_i,b_i)$. We want to arrange them (i.e. determine their left bottom corners) in a way that the area of their union is minimized.

So far, this is at the level of a homework problem, and one optimal configuration is to have all of them to share the left bottom corner.

Now comes a twist. We are asking that the first two rectangles are (internally) disjoint, and they touch in exactly one point on the boundary, every other rectangle is free to move. So let us say left bottom corner of first rectangle and top right corner of second rectangle is $(0,0)$.

What can we say about optimal configurations?

The case where $a_1+a_2\le a_i$ and $b_1+b_2\le b_i$ for some $i$ is easy, so don't consider this.

Most interesting to us is to know how the "twist" changes the minimal area.

Comment: So I don't know about the first two. How about the rest sharing the same center? Gerhard "Seems Pretty Optimal To Me" Paseman, 2019.03.20.

Comment: If the first rectangle is "flat horizontal" and the second "flat vertical", then it might be better to split the other rectangles into two groups, and align the "horizontal" rectangles with the bottom left corner of the first rectangle and the "vertical" rectangles with the top right corner of the second rectangle.